# SQL Query to Group Clusters of Related Events with Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

OK, this is tough to explain without drawing it out on a whiteboard or something... But here it goes.  I've tried to be as clear as possible but let me know if this doesn't make sense....

I have a MS Access project that processes time series datasets from multiple Source Objects or "SOURCES", and multiple observation points or "RECEIVERS", and identifies events of interest based on time and spatial proximity. This gives me a table of triggers of possibly related events with the following fields.

**CORRELATION_ID

RECEIVER_EVENT_ID

RECEIVER_NAME

RECEIVER_START_DATETIME

RECEIVER_END_DATETIME

SOURCE_EVENT_ID

SOURCE_NAME

SOURCE_START_DATETIME

SOURCE_END_DATETIME**

Because I can get multiple source and receiver triggers happening at overlapping times, or times that are close to each other, I get a massive list of triggers and I would like to refine this list of triggers by grouping them further based on additional criteria.

I would like to specify 2 criteria for max allowable time gap between source events, MAX_SOURCE_GAP, and maximum allowable gap between receiver events MAX_RECEIVER_GAP.  GAP is calculated from Start time of one trigger minus the end time of another trigger.

If the events are within this gap range then they need to be grouped, and the resulting group record must store the start time of the earliest event and the end time of the latest event. For the RECEIVER events, the RECEIVER_NAME must be the same. (ie I dont want to group events from different RECEIVERS because I still want to end up with a list of related RECEIVER<>SOURCE events)   For the SOURCE events, the event must have been picked up by the same Receiver, in otherwords the RECEIVER_NAME again must be the same.   I would also like the record to return a list of the names of either the Sources that are grouped.  For this I was thinking I could implement Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() function.

***updated*** The 3rd criteria required defines the relationship between the grouped source events and the grouped receiver events, MAX_SOURCE_TO_RECEIVER_DELAY.  This is the maximum allowable time delay after start time of a source that the receiver can be triggered.  In otherwords  startTime_receiver - startTime_source <= MAX_SOURCE_TO_RECEIVER_DELAY.  The receiver can also not trigger before the source, so startTime_receiver < startTime_source.

I think basically this will require a few steps.  At least one subquery to group the SOURCE events.  At least one subquery to group the RECEIVER events. And then a step to combine them so I can return something like this.

**RECEIVER_NAME

MIN-RECEIVER_START_DATETIME

MAX-RECEIVER_END_DATETIME

MIN-SOURCE_END_DATETIME

MAX-SOURCE_END_DATETIME

LIST_OF_SOURCES**   <--field that looks like "SOURCE10, SOURCE 24, SOURCE 51"  generated from [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

I think I understand the methodology but I am having trouble properly grouping things where there are more than 2 triggers. I can probably tackle concatenating the names of the sources with ConcatRelated if I get the proper time grouping figured out.

--Update -
**I have uploaded some sample data to SQLfiddle.com** [click here for sample dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35bad/1)

The resulting table I am essentially trying to come up with would look like this for this sample data set:

```
RECEIVER_NAME    MIN-RECEIVER_START_DATETIME   MAX-RECEIVER_END_DATETIME    SOURCE_LIST               MIN-SOURCE_START_DATETIME    MAX-SOURCE_END_DATETIME
RECEIVER1        2012-04-08 05:08              2012-04-08 06:22             SOURCE1,SOURCE2,SOURCE3   2012-04-08 02:10             2012-04-08 05:25
RECEIVER2        2012-05-08 10:05              2012-04-08 14:55             SOURCE1,SOURCE2           2012-05-08 10:01             2012-05-08 13:45
RECEIVER2        2012-06-08 06:55              2012-06-08 21:19             SOURCE2                   2012-05-08 14:55             2012-05-08 16:22
```

sorry, wow what a pain trying to post a table. I couldn't find any better way.

Comment: (1) Choose which database you are using, SQL Server or MS Access; (2) If you have trouble explaining something, show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Start with sqlfiddle.com as a good place to put together sample data.

Comment: Your logic has couple of problems: because you have two criteria you will still produce duplicate records. 
second problem is: grouping start and end time by max_allowed_time_Gap will group everything regardless of their start & end time.
eg: max_allowed_gap = 10mins: st01:00, et01:10 and st02:00, et02:10 will be grouped together.
what you can do: Reduce the criteria to one like records between (receiver_start_time) and (REceiver_end_time) you have a chance to get Min and Max values from receiver & source dateTimes. group by timeline then you have hourly triggers.

Comment: @krish-km That makes sense, I realized I left out the criteria to relate the source and receiver events, which is a maximum delay time between the start of the source trigger and receiver trigger. I've added it above...

Comment: @user1243468: do you really have to do this in access? because Access/Jet isn't well known for such operations. it doesn't mean you can't do it in Access. Access might take its time for such operations where other SQL engine do it easily.

Comment: @user1243468: are you expecting such result? http://puu.sh/bjLTd/66bb914b22.png
Note: This is done using MySQL not Access. Also this was achieved without any of your criteria. just grouped by logics

Comment: Yes that looks close to what looking for, can you post the SQL so I can regenerate it, it's cut off in the screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as i mentioned in my comment **no** criteria has been used to yield the result. your events are grouped by RECEIVER_EVENT_ID and RECEIVER_EVENT_START_TIME. ( i guess receiver_event_id is always related  to receiver_name hence i chose event_id but you can also group by receiver_name its up to you)

this will give for now:

1. 240 |     RECEIVER1 | August, 04 2012 05:08:00+0000
2. 241 |     RECEIVER2 | August, 05 2012 10:05:00+0000
3. 242 |     RECEIVER2 | August, 05 2012 14:15:00+0000
4. 243 |     RECEIVER2 | August, 06 2012 06:55:00+0000

then you can find the min and max values related to the events that are being grouped.
if you would like to group the events 241 & 242, you need to find a logic that group them both together.

here is the code markdown for grouping events and event start time:

Hope this gives you an idea about group_concatenation function in MySQL as well as grouping. Let me know if you have found the exact SQL statement for you question or a faster solution. I'm very much interested to see that too.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35bad/6)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE relatedEvents 
    (
     CORRELATION_ID INT auto_increment primary key, 
     RECEIVER_EVENT_ID INT,
     RECEIVER_NAME VARCHAR(20), 
     RECEIVER_START_DATETIME DATETIME,
     RECEIVER_END_DATETIME DATETIME,
     SOURCE_EVENT_ID INT,
     SOURCE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
     SOURCE_START_DATETIME DATETIME,
     SOURCE_END_DATETIME DATETIME
    );

INSERT INTO relatedEvents
(RECEIVER_EVENT_ID, RECEIVER_NAME, RECEIVER_START_DATETIME, 
  RECEIVER_END_DATETIME, SOURCE_EVENT_ID, SOURCE_NAME, SOURCE_START_DATETIME, SOURCE_END_DATETIME)
VALUES
('240', 'RECEIVER1', '2012-08-04 05:08:00', '2012-08-04 06:22', '1', 'SOURCE1', '2012-08-04 02:10', '2012-08-04 02:40'),
('240', 'RECEIVER1', '2012-08-04 05:08:00', '2012-08-04 06:22', '2', 'SOURCE2', '2012-08-04 02:30', '2012-08-04 03:10'),
('240', 'RECEIVER1', '2012-08-04 05:08:00', '2012-08-04 06:22', '3', 'SOURCE2', '2012-08-04 03:15', '2012-08-04 03:30'),
('240', 'RECEIVER1', '2012-08-04 05:08:00', '2012-08-04 06:22', '4', 'SOURCE3', '2012-08-04 05:01', '2012-08-04 05:25'),
('241', 'RECEIVER2', '2012-08-05 10:05:00', '2012-08-05 10:35', '5', 'SOURCE1', '2012-08-05 10:01', '2012-08-05 10:15'),
('241', 'RECEIVER2', '2012-08-05 10:05:00', '2012-08-05 10:35', '6', 'SOURCE2', '2012-08-05 12:15', '2012-08-05 12:17'),
('242', 'RECEIVER2', '2012-08-05 14:15:00', '2012-08-05 14:55', '7', 'SOURCE1', '2012-08-05 13:35', '2012-08-05 13:45'),
('243', 'RECEIVER2', '2012-08-06 06:55:00', '2012-08-06 21:19', '8', 'SOURCE2', '2012-08-05 14:55', '2012-08-05 16:22');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  RECEIVER_EVENT_ID as EVENT_ID,
  o_r.receiver_name as Receiver_name,
  (select min(RECEIVER_START_DATETIME)from relatedEvents as I_R where ((I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID = O_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)) Group by I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)as min_r_st,
  (select Max(RECEIVER_END_DATETIME)from relatedEvents as I_R where ((I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID = O_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)) Group by I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID) as max_r_et,
  (Select group_concat(DISTINCT source_name) from relatedEvents as I_R where ((I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID = O_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)) Group by I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID) as Sources,
  (select min(SOURCE_START_DATETIME)from relatedEvents as I_R where ((I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID = O_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)) Group by I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)as min_s_st,
  (select Max(SOURCE_END_DATETIME)from relatedEvents as I_R where ((I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID = O_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID)) Group by I_R.RECEIVER_EVENT_ID) as max_s_et,
  count(RECEIVER_START_DATETIME) as RST
FROM relatedEvents as O_R
group by RECEIVER_EVENT_ID, RECEIVER_START_DATETIME
order by RECEIVER_START_DATETIME asc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35bad/6/0)**:

```
| EVENT_ID | RECEIVER_NAME |                      MIN_R_ST |                      MAX_R_ET |                 SOURCES |                      MIN_S_ST |                      MAX_S_ET | RST |
|----------|---------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|-----|
|      240 |     RECEIVER1 | August, 04 2012 05:08:00+0000 | August, 04 2012 06:22:00+0000 | SOURCE1,SOURCE2,SOURCE3 | August, 04 2012 02:10:00+0000 | August, 04 2012 05:25:00+0000 |   4 |
|      241 |     RECEIVER2 | August, 05 2012 10:05:00+0000 | August, 05 2012 10:35:00+0000 |         SOURCE1,SOURCE2 | August, 05 2012 10:01:00+0000 | August, 05 2012 12:17:00+0000 |   2 |
|      242 |     RECEIVER2 | August, 05 2012 14:15:00+0000 | August, 05 2012 14:55:00+0000 |                 SOURCE1 | August, 05 2012 13:35:00+0000 | August, 05 2012 13:45:00+0000 |   1 |
|      243 |     RECEIVER2 | August, 06 2012 06:55:00+0000 | August, 06 2012 21:19:00+0000 |                 SOURCE2 | August, 05 2012 14:55:00+0000 | August, 05 2012 16:22:00+0000 |   1 |
```

Comment: Thanks, the output I'm looking for is similar, except with criteria it may group some of those results differently. If MAX_RECEIVER_GAP = 12 hours, MAX_SOURCE_GAP = 6 hours, and MAX_SOURCE_TO_RECEIVER_DELAY = 18 hours, then it would group event_ID 241 and 242 because the criteria holds for the receiver, source, and source-receiver delay.

Comment: Also, I will have to find a way to make it work within MS Access as I don't have MYSQL capabilities. But if we can figure it out in MYSQL I can try to make it work in access SQL.

Comment: @user1243468: I don't know your exact requirements. you might know more than me. you now have a starting point. fiddle with it :)
Also note: Group function will only work if the values are same. it means your logic/function has to return similar value across all records to be grouped together. Oh yes Access!!!!  Good luck with it :)

Comment: thanks for your help. you certainly are better versed in SQL I only try to hack things together when I need to.   I will try to see if I can get it to work.